# Looking for Serial-controlled PWM generator

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm looking for a chip to generate some PWM signals. Here are my requirements:

- Controllable via serial interface (SPI, I2C, or similar)
- Outputs 10-20 kHz PWM signals (even better if adjustable)
- Outputs should be basic logic level (open-drain, push-pull, etc)

  - Not constant current, buck, boost, etc. I've found *plenty* of LED drivers that can do this, but that won't work here.
- Should be able to run on 3.3 V supply, but 5 V is OK too.
- 8 b resolution is good enough, higher is fine.

I've used (and love) the [PCA9685](https://www.nxp.com/products/analog/interfaces/ic-bus/ic-led-controllers/16-channel-12-bit-pwm-fm-plus-ic-bus-led-controller:PCA9685). It works really well, and is very flexible and easy to use. Sadly it tops out around 1.5 kHz (or 3 kHz with fastest allowed external clock), so I can't use it here.

I found the [LT8500](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8500fb.pdf), but it can only do about 6 kHz and isn't nearly as convenient (external PWM clock needed for example).

My end goal is to control 4 [H-bridge brushed DC motor controllers](https://www.pololu.com/product/2995) from a Raspberry Pi. I need the high frequency to set the motor switching frequency, and I'd like to use a separate chip as the Pi will be doing various other tasks. I don't want to use software PWM, as I don't want to risk the motor going crazy if there is a software hiccup on the Pi.

Comment: I assume you know how to design deadtime in commutation

Comment: Such a part seeking question is, of course, off topic here.  You might however consider using an accessory MCU for this, especially as it gives you the option to implement custom fail-safe logic around the pi's more complicated software stack.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've read the question more like "which *type* of device solves this relatively well-described problem", and ignored the potential "give me device numbers I can order" aspect, which would indeed be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, a significant part of my question, that I guess wasn't super clear, was what kind of device I'm looking for here. I've been browsing around on Digikey's ICs -> PMIC - LED Drivers section, where the PCA9685 was, and have been unable to find anything suitable. Therefore I thought maybe I'm just not looking for the right kind of part.

Comment: A quad I2C to PWM might sound nice, but a quad motor driver board with an ARM chip and 2A drivers for $10 sounds better.

Comment: Can you convert your digital signal to analogue to use the LTC6992? Maybe filter your current slow speed PWM output to DC and drive the LTC6992?

Comment: @Andyaka That's an interesting idea. It feels a bit hacky, but I'll definitely keep it in mind if there are no easier solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the analog way of producing a PWM with a 10 – 20 kHz width

- Use your Raspberry Pi, or some other clock source to generate a sine or triangle or sawtooth wave of desired frequency. A hardware PWM unit of the Pi, followed by a RC low pass that has a cutoff above the fundamental frequency would probably work reasonably well; AC couple the result to a VCC/2 biasing resistive voltage divider.
- Get a [cheap four-channel DAC](http://www.ti.com/product/tlv5620) and use it to generate four threshold voltages
- Get four comparators (or a comparator chip with four channels) to compare analog waveform to threshold voltage. For your lower-kHz range, a quad-opamp IC would probably do; you could also use differential-to-single ended-converters (e.g. as used for robust digital communications). The sky is the limit :)

When using a sine wave (e.g. an actual analog oscillator or a low-passed square wave), your "threshold to PWM width" relationship won't be linear, but you'll probably have enough computational power on the Pi to use a lookup table to solve that problem.

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking I'll combine your idea with Andy aka's suggestion. Use a DAC to generate an analogue voltage, then an analogue-to-PWM converter like the LTC6992. This avoids having to generate my own square/sawtooth/etc signals, provides a reasonably nice solution, with a reasonably low partcount.

Answer (score 2):

If the "program your own microcontroller" route seems to complex:

You can cheat programming the microcontroller completely!

Get a MCU that has enough PWM units (e.g. the [STM32F100C8](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/stm32f100c8t7btr/stmicroelectronics?utm_campaign=octopart_2018&utm_currency=EUR&utm_keyword=STM32F100C8T7BTR&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_content=inv_listing&utm_source=octopart) mentioned above). Just compile the minimum code necessary to set up all the clock speeds and IO ports; luckily, manufacturers like ST deliver graphical tools to generate that code for you. You really just have to open one of their recommended IDEs and hit "compile" and "flash". If you buy a ST Nucleo board, you get a flasher + eval board + MCU for the price of pretty much 2× the MCU, so that'll be relatively straight forward.

Then, you abuse it as puppet, by putting it into debug mode and interacting with its PWM peripherals using SWD (serial wire debug) interface.

The idea comes from Micah Scott's article in [PoC||GTFO 0x10, p. 26ff](https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/).

You install OpenOCD on your Pi, then you follow one of the many guides online explaining how to use the Pi GPIO as SWD interface; they all boil down to having an OpenOCD .cfg file containing

```
interface bcm2835gpio
```

and the other settings necessary to a) make OpenOCD speak correctly to your Pi's GPIO, and b) make OpenOCD speak SWD in a manner compatible with your microcontroller. One example (which I didn't test, though) can be found [here](https://movr0.com/2016/09/02/use-raspberry-pi-23-as-a-jtagswd-adapter/).

Once that has been set up, you can just run `openocd -f yourconfigfile.cfg`, have it connect to the microcontroller via SWD, and then connect to TCP socket 4444 (typically) on localhost. You can then issue [commands](http://openocd.org/doc/html/General-Commands.html) like `mww` to write to arbitrary memory addresses. You just modify hardware registers as necessary to set up the PWM channels to your liking (or adjust them). You can find the right settings in the programming guide of your microcontroller (it's not much harder than figuring out what to write over I²C to make an I²C-based PWM controller do your work).

Another route, especially if you're familiar with python, is to use the PyGPIO lib and do it [directly](https://www.disk91.com/2015/technology/programming/swd-programming-using-a-raspberrypi/) without going through debuggers like OpenOCD.

Comment: This is really interesting, and definitely new to me. Thanks a lot for actually trying to come up with some ideas, and not just marking as off topic for no good reason like the other 4 people.

Comment: Learning about PoC||GTFO makes this whole thread worth it.

Answer (score 1):

> My end goal is to control 4 H-bridge motor controllers from a Raspberry Pi

Sounds like you actually want an H-Bridge that is controllable via serial line, not an H-Bridge driver that is controllable + H-Bridge.

TI has such devices, e.g. [DRV8830](http://www.ti.com/product/drv8830), but that's more designed for smaller motors (<= 1A). But the motor driver category has loads of things!

If this is for a stepper motor: there's dedicated stepper motor drivers, that actually take care of generating the offset-phased PWMs for you from a single control! That makes things easier, and cheaper. They also exist with built-in H-Bridges, if you want to save on complexity, space or cost (and your motor isn't *too* beefy).

If you really need to control your own H-Bridge drivers: I'm pretty certain that the easiest, and most cost-efficient, way to do that is getting a microcontroller to do that. Since controlling multiple whatever-drivers as a slave to a main controller is an extremely common job, e.g. in automotive applications, there's loads and loads of microcontrollers that have more than plenty PWM units. In fact, there's dedicated product lines that are advertised for exactly that, motor control. (but to be honest, every mid-range microcontroller, eg. STM32F100 and up, would have sufficient PWM units.)

The NXP Kinetis-V series comes to mind. Those are relatively mighty processors, but they come with all the bells and whistles you'd need for motor control, and things like motor control designer software (which I've never tried).

Lower-cost controllers like the [STM32F10?](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32-mainstream-mcus/stm32f1-series/stm32f100-value-line.html?querycriteria=productId=LN775) can be had [shy of 2€](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/stm32f100c8t7btr/stmicroelectronics?utm_campaign=octopart_2018&utm_currency=EUR&utm_keyword=STM32F100C8T7BTR&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_content=inv_listing&utm_source=octopart) and have 7 timers, of which TIM1 alone would suffice to generate 4 different PWMs from the same clock source, including automatic dead times (super important for H-Bridge control).

That's still a relatively mighty controller – 32 bit core, lots of serial peripherals to choose from (3× UART, 2× SPI, 2× I²C, and you can still bitbang or write your own interrupt-driven synchronous serial), and it comes with a widely supported architecture; there's multiple RTOSes that you can choose from, so that you don't have to write your own task management (getting commands from the serial peripheral, and translating that to PWM settings).

Comment: I had a feeling MCUs would be the likely answer. I'm really not keen on this approach, as it would require a ton of time, and some additional costs to implement (learning the IDE and toolset, acquiring and learning to use the programmer, understanding and writing the needed code, etc), as opposed to a dedicated chip that can simply be included in the design like I had previously. Also, sadly using a different driver is no longer an option, as [they](https://www.pololu.com/product/2995) have already been purchased.

Comment: Not too bad a driver! So, we're talking about driving a DC motor driver, gotcha. That means I'm not convinced that LED drivers really don't work. Why do you say that's the case?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, not really being familiar with how some of them work. I simply thought that the output circuitry used for driving LEDs (like a constant current driver) simply would not be able to interface with the motor controller's PWM input circuitry appropriately. If I'm mistaken there, please do explain. I simply specified open drain/push-pull/etc because that's what I know how to use, and what the PCA9685 was when I used it on the previous iteration (using a slower signalled motor controller).

Comment: basically, linear, low-side LED drivers (that aren't constant current drivers) typically are simply open collector or open drain "current sinks", in the way that "LED on" means that you "short" the output pin to ground. Dimming for these just means PWM'ing that. Replace the LED with a pull-up resistor, and you get an open-drain PWM generator, i.e. good at pulling low, a little slower on pulling up. What you could do is LED driver with Pull-up -> inverting schmitt trigger -> PWM input of your motor driver, so that a) the reduced high.output drive capability doesn't matter (only drives the inv.)

Comment: and b) "LED off" actually means "PWM off" (and you don't have to invert the logic). Luckily, inverters can be bought in many-channel IC packages, so having four LED driver outputs connected to four inverter channels doesn't have to be a componentfest.

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, this is just what I did in the previous iteration of this design, with the PCA9685. I configured it to use open-drain mode, with a pull-up resistor. (Didn't bother with any kind of inverter or buffer, instead using the PCA9685's built-in invert option). This worked great for the motor controller I used then which specifically wanted a 333Hz PWM signal. Now that the frequency needs to be 10-20KHz, I can't find any parts that behave in this manner that can go at that frequency.

Comment: hm! The [TLC59461](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc59461) has an external input for the PWM clock, and does 12 bit PWM counting, so the PWM frequency is GSCLK/4096; the maximum \$f_\text{GSCLK}\$ is 33 MHz, so you "barely" reach 8.06 kHz. Would that be "close enough"?